# javafx TableView not populatng data from the database

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I'm not able to populate the data from the sqlite database. It is just displaying cells n the table but there is no data. I'm new to javafx so please forgive me if there are any huge mistakes.

This is the controller class

```
public class ReportController implements Initializable {

//report page variables
@FXML private Label nameLabelReport;
@FXML private Label addressLabelReport;
@FXML private TextField memberIdField;
@FXML private TextField locationField;
@FXML private Button memberSearchBtn;
@FXML private Button locationSearchBtn;
 //Report table variables
@FXML private TableView reportTable;
@FXML private TableColumn memberColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn nameColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn addressColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn phoneNoColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn emailColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn designationColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn siteNoColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn locationColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn sqftColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn totalAmtColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn advanceColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn toBePaidColumn;
private static Connection con;
private static Statement stat;
private PreparedStatement prep;
private static ObservableList<UserData> data;

@FXML
protected void handleReportSearch(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {

         System.out.println("Entered else");
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:housing_society.db");
            stat = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Entered else");

            String location;

            location = locationField.getText();
            System.out.println("Connected to database "+location);
            ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM society_members WHERE site_location like '"+ location + "'");
            while (rs.next()) {
                UserData userData = new UserData(rs.getString("membership_id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("address"), rs.getString("phone_number"), rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("working_organization"), rs.getString("designation"), rs.getString("site_no"), rs.getString("site_location"), rs.getFloat("per_square_feet_charges"),rs.getFloat("total_amount"), rs.getFloat("paid_in_advance"), rs.getFloat("to_be_paid"));

                data.add(userData);
             }   





        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    memberColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("membershipID") );
           nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Name") );
           addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("address") );
           phoneNoColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("phoneNo") );
           emailColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("email") );
           designationColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("designation") );
           siteNoColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("siteNo") );
           locationColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("location") );
           sqftColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("perSqFt") );
           totalAmtColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("totalAmt") );
           advanceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("paidInAdvance") );
           toBePaidColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("toBePaid") );

           data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
           reportTable.setItems(data);

}

private static class UserData {

    public StringProperty membershipID;
    public StringProperty Name;
    public StringProperty address;
    public StringProperty phoneNo;
    public StringProperty email; 
    public StringProperty workingOrganization;
    public StringProperty designation;
    public StringProperty siteNo;
    public StringProperty location;
    public FloatProperty perSqFt;
    public FloatProperty totalAmt;
    public FloatProperty paidInAdvance;
    public FloatProperty toBePaid;

    public UserData(String membershipID, String Name, String address,String phoneNo, String email, String workingOrganization, String designation, String siteNo, String location, float perSqFt, float totalAmt, float paidInAdvance, float toBePaid) {
        this.membershipID = new SimpleStringProperty(membershipID);
        this.Name = new SimpleStringProperty(Name);
        this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
        this.phoneNo = new SimpleStringProperty(phoneNo);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        this.workingOrganization = new SimpleStringProperty(workingOrganization);
        this.designation = new SimpleStringProperty(designation);
        this.location = new SimpleStringProperty(location);
        this.siteNo = new SimpleStringProperty(siteNo);
        this.perSqFt = new SimpleFloatProperty(perSqFt);
        this.totalAmt = new SimpleFloatProperty(totalAmt);
        this.paidInAdvance = new SimpleFloatProperty(paidInAdvance);
        this.toBePaid = new SimpleFloatProperty(toBePaid);

    }

    public StringProperty getMembershipID() {
        return membershipID;
    }

    public StringProperty getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public StringProperty getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public StringProperty getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public StringProperty getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public StringProperty getWorkingOrganization() {
        return workingOrganization;
    }

    public StringProperty getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public StringProperty getSiteNo() {
        return siteNo;
    }

    public StringProperty getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public FloatProperty getPerSqFt() {
        return perSqFt;
    }

    public FloatProperty getTotalAmt() {
        return totalAmt;
    }

    public FloatProperty getPaidInAdvance() {
        return paidInAdvance;
    }

    public FloatProperty getToBePaid() {
        return toBePaid;
    }
}

}
```

I will not include the FXML file because it will make this question very big and complicated.I will just the add the lines which are necessary.

Link to controller

```
 <BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="postalhs.ReportController">
```

This is the button tag. When clicked will call `handleReportSearch` method

```
<Button onMouseClicked="#handleReportSearch" fx:id="locationSearchBtn" layoutX="344.0" layoutY="172.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Search" />
```

TableView

```
<TableView fx:id="reportTable" prefHeight="238.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
      <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="memberColumn" prefWidth="93.0" text="Membership ID" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" prefWidth="57.0" text="Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="addressColumn" prefWidth="60.0" text="Address" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="phoneNoColumn" prefWidth="90.0" text="Phone Number" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="emailColumn" prefWidth="69.0" text="Email" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="designationColumn" prefWidth="81.0" text="Designation" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="siteNoColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Site Number" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="locationColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Site Location" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="sqftColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Per square feet charges" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="totalAmtColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Total Amount" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="advanceColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Paid in Advance" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="toBePaidColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="To Be Paid" />
        </columns>
 </TableView>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you lost the `}` from the end of the `while` loop in the copy and paste to SO... Presumably you have checked you are not getting an exception in the database access code. Can you log the value of `data.size()` after it's populated from the database code, to make sure you're actually getting something from there?

Comment: Yeah i'm not getting any exception in database code . here is the `data.size()` output `size:2` n correct i have missed the `}` while copy pasting the code. my bad

Comment: `new PropertyValueFactory("Name")` should be `new PropertyValueFactory("name")`.

Comment: `UserData` class should be public or I don't think the reflection used by the `PropertyValueFactory` to lookup the appropriate property value will work.

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX 8 may be different, but JavaFX 2 requires `Property` methods to be reflective in order to successfully bind with a value. Modify your current UserData class methods (or add new ones) that meet the `Property` method convention (i.e. "Property()").

Like this:

```
public StringProperty membershipIDProperty() {
    return membershipID;
}
```

Comment: I modified the method names in UserData but still the rows are not populated :(

Comment: `PropertyValueFactory` doesn't actually require those methods: if they don't exist it will fall back to the corresponding `get..()` method, as per the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html)

Comment: @James_D. I misread the source for the `PropertyReference` class. I could swear I remember correcting the same issue personally with this approach but I must be mistaken.

Comment: `getName()` should return `String` (that is the fallback type) not `StringProperty`.  If you want `PropertyValueFactory` to work with a method which returns a `Property` the method must be named `someMemberProperty()` not `getMember()`.

Comment: After many failed  attempts at `TableView`. I just generated a report file which will contain the table contents n a file and displayed the file contents in TextArea. But thanks for all your help , I will surely try the above methods after the completion of the project and post the results n case it is required by future searchers.